# How to prevent dynamic casting or implement a template method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have made a factory function that returns an abstract class bases on enum values. Now my goal is to provide the abstract class for a certain set of enum values and provide the direct class for the other set.

My code:

```
 public Component CreateComponent(string identifier, ComponentType type) => type switch
    {
        ComponentType.AND => new AndNode(identifier),
        ComponentType.NAND => new NAndNode(identifier),
        ComponentType.NOR => new NOrNode(identifier),
        ComponentType.NOT => new NotNode(identifier),
        ComponentType.OR => new OrNode(identifier),
        ComponentType.XOR => new XOrNode(identifier),
        ComponentType.PROBE => new Probe(identifier),
        ComponentType.INPUT_LOW => new InputBit(identifier, 1),
        ComponentType.INPUT_HIGH => new InputBit(identifier, 2),
        _ => throw new ArgumentException(message: "invalid enum value", paramName: nameof(type))
    };
```

My goal is that every type returns a Component class, but the INPUT_HIGH and INPUT_LOW should provide me with the InputBit class. I can't think of a solution, which doesn't include type checking (dynamic casting or using 'is'). Besides from my understanding C# does not have a template method like C++ does.

**Edit:**
I need a List with all the Components and a List with all the InputBits in the class that calls this function. At the moment I am able to get a list of all the Components like this:

```
components.Add(factory.CreateComponent(node_description.identifier, type));
```

I need a list of the InputBits as well. So I can check what the factory returns by type checking, but I'm trying to prevent that. Is there an ideal solution?

Comment: Can you add a sample usage of the `Component` object so that you need to cast it to a concrete implementation (`InputBit`, for example)?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I edited the original post, hope that helps out.

Comment: Making a `CreateComponent` method generic can help you. How are `components` declared and used?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't know how to make the method generic (see comment below). ```components``` is a ```List<Component>```. I used it to loop through the components and execute an action, but I want to execute a specific action for InputBit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Template methods can be implemented in C# using [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods). See below an alternative implementation using generics.

```
            public class Component
            {
                public string Identifier { get; set; }
                //...
            }

            public class InputBit: Component
            {
                public int InputType { get; set; }
                //...
            }

            public class AndNode:Component
            {
                //...
            }

            //...

            public T CreateComponent<T>(string identifier, int inputType=0) where T:Component, new()
            {
                var component = new T
                {
                    Identifier = identifier
                };
                if (component is InputBit)
                {
                    (component as InputBit).InputType = inputType;
                }
                return component;
            }
```

Comment: Looks like that's what I'm looking for. However I get: Cannot convert expression of type 'AndNode' to T. How do I fix that? https://pastebin.com/mEq5Xs9h

Comment: To invoke CreateComponent method, you should provide the type. For example:                            
` var components = new List<Component>();
 components.Add(CreateComponent<AndNode>("Test Identifier"));
 components.Add(CreateComponent<InputBit>("Test Identifier", 1));`

Comment: For a complete working example see https://dotnetfiddle.net/9FGy0a